# Convert String to Array of Arrays in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to convert what seems to be a string into an array of arrays. I'm uploading an excel sheet using read_excel but one of the columns is formatted:

```
[[u'MAKER', u'CREATED', u'1463538547', None], ['SHOP', u'ACCEPTED', u'1463538651', None], [u'SHOP', u'READY', u'1463539221', None], [u'COURIER', u'COMPLETED', u'1463540801', None]]
```

It's reading this as a complete string but I want it to be read as an array of arrays so I loop over each array. This is what I'm using to intake the file

```
changes = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', sheet_name = "changes").
```

I tried changing the type to list but that doesn't seem to help.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: What is the column name that has the array of arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = "['a',['b','c','d'],'e']"
>>> print(literal_eval(s))
['a', ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? change 'array_column_name' to the actual column name

```
changes = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', sheet_name = "changes",converters={'array_column_name':ast.literal_eval})
```

Comment: I get an error of TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Every time i tried to do a second loop to view the inner array it would treat the array as a string so it would loop through the letters. Doing the below got me what i wanted, thanks!

for row in changes['array_list']:
    for item in ast.literal_eval(row):
        print(item)